# Different int sizes on my computer and Arduino

Tags: c, portability, arduino

Im working on a sparetime project, making some server code to an Arduino Duemilanove, but before I test this code on the controller I am testing it on my own machine (An OS X based macbook). I am using ints some places, and I am worried that this will bring up strange errors when code is compiled and run on the Arduino Duemilanove because the Arduino handles ints as 2 bytes, and my macbook handles ints as 4 bytes. Im not a hardcore C and C++ programmer, so I am in a bit of worry how an experienced programmer would handle this situation.
Should I restrict the code with a typedef that wrap my own definition of and int that is restricted to 2 bytes? Or is there another way around?

Comment: Isn't there a suitable Arduino simulator?

Comment: pjc50 I havent found one yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the `stdint.h` header.  It defines typedefs that explicitly refer to the signedness and size of your variables.  For example, a 16-bit unsigned integer is a `uint16_t`.  It's part of the C99 standard, so it's available pretty much everywhere.  See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h

Comment: I liked this answer because you gave me the link, and explained me some about the definitions.

Answer (score 6):

The C standard defines an int as being a signed type large enough to at least hold all integers between -32768 and 32767 - implementations are free to choose larger types, and any modern *32-bit* system will choose a 32-bit integer. However, as you've seen, some embedded platforms still use 16-bit ints. I would recommend using `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` if your arduino compiler supports it; if not, use preprocessor macros to typedef those types yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to handle the situation is to choose the type based on the values it will need to represent:

- If it's a general small integer, and the range -32767 to 32767 is OK, use `int`;
- Otherwise, if the range -2147483647 to 2147483647 is OK, use `long`;
- Otherwise, use `long long`.
- If the range -32767 to 32767 is OK *and space efficiency is important*, use `short` (or `signed char`, if the range -127 to 127 is OK).

As long as you have made no other assumptions that these (ie. always using `sizeof` instead of assuming the width of the type), then your code will be portable.

In general, you should only need to use the fixed-width types from `stdint.h` for values that are being exchanged through a binary interface with another system - ie. being read from or written to the network or a file.

Answer (score 2):

Will you need values smaller than −32,768 or bigger than +32,767? If not, ignore the differnt sizes. If you do need them, there's stdint.h with fixed-size integers, singned und unsigned, called intN_t/uintN_t (N = number of bits). It's C99, but most compilers will support it. Note that using integers with a size bigger than the CPU's wordsize (16 bit in this case) will hurt performance, as there are no native instructions for handling them.

Comment: I have thought about just ignoring it, but then again, I know that this could mislead me in some way later in the project.

Answer (score 0):

avoid using the type `int` as it's size can depend upon architecture / compiler.

use `short` and `long` instead

Comment: Is that defined somewhere, that short and long is system independend? Because that sounds like a very good solution to my problem.

Comment: @mslot - no it's not.  There are some constraints, but you shouldn't rely on them.  Where you target specific hardware you should use appropriate fixed-size types as mentioned by bdonlan and phooky.  Use a typedef as well, and you can target other hardware easily.

Comment: @mslot ues short is defined to be no longer than long, and long is defined to be no shorter than short - other than that you are on your own