# Why do I get a negative number when adding two ints together whose sum is > 32k?

Tags: c++, arduino, integer, processing, overflow

I have a question that seems really simple, but I think there's something in Processing that I'm not grokking. The issue is that when I add two ints together and the final amount is > 32k, the amount becomes negative.

Seems like an overflow issue except that the Processing reference states

> Datatype for integers, numbers without a decimal point. Integers can be as large as 2,147,483,647 and as low as -2,147,483,648.

Here's the offending code and the Serial Monitor output:

```
int start_millis = millis();
int end_millis = start_millis + 5000;
  
Serial.println(start_millis);
Serial.println("");
Serial.println(end_millis);
```

And the monitor output:

```
!---Motion Detected; Flicker starting ---!
17616
22616
!--- Flicker Over ---!

!---Motion Detected; Flicker starting ---!
22986
27986
!--- Flicker Over ---!

!---Motion Detected; Flicker starting ---!
29569
-30967
```

Comment: Post and ye shall recieve. From the Arduino docs:

On the Arduino Uno (and other ATmega based boards) an int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767 (minimum value of -2^15 and a maximum value of (2^15) - 1).

Answer (score 1):

> "Datatype for integers, numbers without a decimal point. Integers can be as large as 2,147,483,647 and as low as -2,147,483,648. "

What's the "Processing reference"? Its statement above is wrong

**Edit:** as commented below, the statement is correct in [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) language, but you're looking at the wrong manual. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is **not** C or C++ so checking it for other languages' features makes absolutely zero sense

In C and C++ standards `int` is a type that has *at least* 16 bits. In 8-bit and 16-bit architectures for obvious practical and performance reasons int is a 16-bit type. Therefore adding 2 numbers whose sum is larger than 32767 results in an overflow (since `INT_MAX == 32767` in that case)

From Arduino docs:

> On the Arduino Uno (and other ATmega based boards) an int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767 (minimum value of -2^15 and a maximum value of (2^15) - 1). On the Arduino Due and SAMD based boards (like MKR1000 and Zero), an int stores a 32-bit (4-byte) value. This yields a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31) - 1).
>
> https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

For more information read

- [Different int sizes on my computer and Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3294816/995714)
- [Is the size of C "int" 2 bytes or 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11438794/995714)
- [Why does the size of an int vary in some compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893712/995714)
- [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/995714)
- [What determines the size of integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13764892/995714)

Comment: [Processing](https://processing.org/) is built on top of Java, not on C or C++, so its [reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is correct.

Comment: Right, I'm saying OP is confused because the Processing reference is for Java, but they're using it on Arduino, so they're at the mercy of C++ types, not Java types. In other words, the Processing reference is not wrong, because it's not talking about Arduino.