# Difference in the output between the C code and the Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, gcc, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

Why there is difference in the output of pointer size between the C code and the Arduino IDE

Comment: Pointer sizes are system and binary dependent. Usually either 8 bytes or 4 bytes which looks like the case respectively in your examples.

Comment: Yes I think that. Is there any way to make them the same size?

Comment: Firstly, why would you want to make them the same size? If you have a 32 bit processor then it can't run a 64 bit binary. Some 64 bit systems can run 32 bit binaries. If you really must then you can build a 32 bit binary using the appropriate compile flags (e.g `-m32`).

Comment: Does that mean if I run the C code on a 32-bit operating system, I will get a result similar to esp32? because the cpu of esp32 is  32-bit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different int sizes on my computer and Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294816/different-int-sizes-on-my-computer-and-arduino)

Answer (score 1):

I will simplify your problem:

In your computer:

```
int *int_pointer;
printf("Size of int_pointer: %d", sizeof(int_pointer)); // Output: 8
```

In your ESP32:

```
int *int_pointer;
printf("Size of int_pointer: %d\n", sizeof(int_pointer)); // Output: 4
```

That is the difference.

A pointer stores a memory address so its size will be (at least) the same as the size of an address in its respective processor.

- Your computer is a 64-bit system -> The size of each address is 8 bytes -> The pointer needs to have 8 bytes to be able to store it.
- Your ESP32 is a 32-bit system -> The size of each address is 4 bytes -> The pointer only needs to have 4 bytes to be able to store it.

Comment: Can I increase the size of pointer in esp32? in any way ? I need the same output

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. At most, you can either compile the program on a 32-bit system or force it using the option `-m` as @kaylum said.

Answer (score 0):

This stuct

```
typedef struct str
{  
  int* array; 
  int y;
  int z;
} str;
```

contains a pointer (int * array). The size of pointers depends on where the code is running. On a 32 bit machine they will be 4 bytes, on a 64 bit machine 8. There can be other sizes to (2 - pdp 11, 6 - some mainframes)

So the sizeof operator will return different values on different systems

Comment: Can I increase the size of pointer in esp32? in any way ? I need the same output

Comment: @kayla the only way to make them the same - and I have no idea why you would want them the same ,its meaningless - is to run the c code that gives 16 as the output in 32 bit mode, which may be possible depending on the platform. But this is a very odd request and I suspect you are doing something EXTREMELY wrong